# UglifyJS Don't Mangle Specific Associative Array

Tags: javascript, regex, uglifyjs

All our webservices are passed to our XHR via an associative array. IE:

```
new XHR({"year": 2015, "week": 6}, ...);
```

All our scripts are added to a single file, and this is then Uglified via (Essentially mangle and compress everything except for our entry point):

```
uglifyjs --mangle toplevel --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle-regex="/(?s)^((?!$$).)*$/" --reserve-domprops --reserved-file reserved -- input
```

The problem is, the `year` and `week` field keep getting obfuscated. So I tried putting a `$$` infront, so we now have `$$year` and `$$week`. To get this to work, I added the regex argument to the UglifyJS command above. I am trying to negate the lookup, so it will mangle all properties except those with a `$$` at the start (Can be any set of characters, just using `$$` as a starting point).

My questions:

1. Is this the best way to do it? Is there a way in UglifyJS to ignore certain associative arrays?
2. Is my regex right? I've tried escaping the two dollar signs, I've tried with `__` instead of `$$` as well as several other attempts (Note: My regex is not good)
3. If the regex is wrong, is there somewhere that would detail a method for creating a valid regex?

**EDIT:** Resolved. Needed to use this:

```
uglifyjs --mangle toplevel --screw-ie8 --mangle-props --mangle-regex="/^((?!\$\$).)*$/" --reserve-domprops --reserved-file reserved -- input > output
```

Comment: It could be that `--reserve-domprops` is implicitly turning on `--mangle-props`. Try taking that out. Also, what is the `(?s)` at the beginning of your regexp?

Comment: the entire regex I used was from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: With regard to your edit, glad it worked, but it is still a mystery why property names were getting mangled in the first place. That should not happen in the absence of `--mangle-props`. I cannot reproduce this on my machine. Are you sure `uglifyjs` is referring to the node executable itself and not some script which is adding options?

Comment: I'm on a windows box with npm installed. And in my path I've got the default uglify js path that was added. The --mangle-regex I think was not working at all maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `UglifyJs v2.4.10` with these arguments:

```
uglifyjs src.js --mangle toplevel --screw-ie8 --compress --reserve-domprops --mangle-regex="/(?s)^((?!$$).)*$/"
```

And it converted this:

```
(function(lib){
    var xhr = new XHR({"year": 2015, "week": 6});
    xhr.run();
})(library);
```

to this:

```
!function(r){var e=new XHR({year:2015,week:6});e.run()}(library);
```

I am unable to get the other options to work properly.

Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.4.24. What do you mean by other commands not working?